# pdf is opening slowly in safari browser in window

Tags: php, yii

I have done creating pdf in `yii framework`. When I export a **pdf**,then I can perfectly create PDF in **chrome**, **firefox** but I am having problem that it takes enough time to create PDF in safari specially in window 7 but again it works good in Mac safari. What can cause such problem in window safari browser?

If any have previously solve this problem please let me know or anyone have idea regarding can please share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are exporting the data form the web-content, for fast exporting you should add following. Check whether you have added already.

### **Either In Action:**

```
$filename  = 'test.pdf';
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```

### **Or In .htacess file**

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

Make sure and inform whether the problem is with browser or streaming the content.